# How can i fix this equals on primitive type(int)

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

heres my code for a library application

```
package com.accenture.totalbeginner;

public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int maximumbooks;

  public Person() {
    name = "unknown name";
    maximumbooks = 3;
  }

  public    String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String anyname)   {
    name = anyname;
  }

  public int getMaximumbooks() {
    return maximumbooks;
  }

  public void setMaximumbooks(int maximumbooks) {
    this.maximumbooks = maximumbooks;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.getName() + " (" + this.getMaximumbooks()  + " books)";
  }

  public boolean equals(Person p1) {
    if(!this.getName().equals(p1.getName()))    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!this.getMaximumbooks().equals(p1.getMaximumbooks()))    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}

(!this.getMaximumbooks().equals(p1.getMaximumbooks()))
```

> this is saying cannot invoke .equals on primitive type(int)

I know what that means, but I have tried everything and I can't think how to correct it.

If you need any of the code from other classes let me know.

Comment: use `==` to compare primitives

Comment: Use `==` not `.equals()` for primitives

Comment: Side note on code quality: use camlCase also for your variable names. And - do it like it should be done; it should read `getMaximumBooks()` for example.

Answer (score 12):

`equals()` is used for `Object`s (`String`, `Integer`, etc...)

For **primitives** like `int`, `boolean`, `char` etc, you have to use `==`

Answer (score 3):

`getMaximumbooks()` returns a primitive type `int` not an `Object`. You have to compare it with `==` or in you case `!=` (not `equals`)

```
if (this.getMaximumbooks() != p1.getMaximumbooks())
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `==` if you're comparing primitives.

Also, try not to use `getters` when working into the class because you have already access to all the fields (`private` or not).

```
public boolean equals(Person p1)
{
    return this.maximumBooks == p1.getMaximumBooks();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot invoke `equals(int)` on the primitive type `int`

[image: Cannot invoke equals(int) on the primitive type int]

`.equals()` is a method which is used only in objects
for `int` , `double` just as in the picture I have attached, use (==)
e.g (int a == int b)